# Transfer a table from a server to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Besides from Import and Export Wizard, Is there any query to transfer a table from a server to another server in SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT * INTO [Server1].[db_name].[dbo].[table_name]
FROM [Server2].[db_name].[dbo].[table_name]
```

Comment: Linked server and 4 part names like you show it. My experience it that it is more efficient running on the into server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options.  If you have the correct permissions, you can create a Linked Server following instructions here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

and then use OPENQUERY (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) to select the records:

```
SELECT * INTO new_db.new_schema.new_table
FROM OPENQUERY(linked_server_name, 'select * from old_db.old_schema.old_table');
```

Or you can do something similar with OPENROWSET (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) if you don't want to go through setting up the linked server:

```
SELECT * INTO new_db.new_schema.new_table
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=OldServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'select * from old_db.old_schema.old_table');
```

Both may require some tweaking based on the authentication method you're using, usernames, privileges, and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can log into Server1, and have a linked server setup for Server2, another option is `OPENQUERY`.

```
SELECT * 
INTO [db_name].[dbo].[table_name]
FROM OPENQUERY([Server2], 'select * from [db_name].[dbo].[table_name]')
```

Keep in mind, this will not copy indexes/statistics.  Those would need to be scripted and re-created.

If you need to keep them in sync, then I would look into SQL Replication.

Comment: If the table has an IDENTITY column then you can also preserve those values by adding SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON...(do insert)...SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name OFF

Comment: You don't need that on a `SELECT... INTO...`, but you would if the table existed and you wanted to `INSERT INTO...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a linked server to server2 inside server1, then run the query in server1:

```
SELECT * INTO [db_name].[dbo].[table_name]
FROM [Server2].[db_name].[dbo].[table_name]
```

More about linked servers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both server1 and server2 are sql server then You do not need a openquery. Create a linked server on server1 for server2 and write query

select * into server1.schema.table_name 
from server2.schema.table_name